# Programmatically moving UITableViewCell fails if manually moved first

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, drag-and-drop

I have a UITableView containing custom cells. These cells are able to be manually moved. In addition, a switch on the cell causes it to be moved to the bottom. The switch works fine if it is used separately from drag-to-reorder. However, if I drag-to-reorder first, then use a switch, I get the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (4) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

The controller has the following code relating to the table:

```
//Table Delegate/Datasource
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let object = self.eventTypes[sourceIndexPath.row]
    self.eventTypes.insertObject(object, atIndex: sourceIndexPath.row)
    self.eventTypes.removeObject(sourceIndexPath.row)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:S360SEventTypeTableCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(XIBFiles.EVENTTYPETABLECELL) as? S360SEventTypeTableCell

    if ((cell == nil)){
        tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: XIBFiles.EVENTTYPETABLECELL, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: XIBFiles.EVENTTYPETABLECELL)
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(XIBFiles.EVENTTYPETABLECELL) as? S360SEventTypeTableCell
    }

    let eventType = eventTypes[indexPath.row]

    cell!.iconImg.image = Images.get_event_image(eventType["title"]! as! String)
    cell!.titleLbl.text = (eventType["title"]! as! String)


    return cell!
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return eventTypes.count
}
```

The custom cell has the following code:

```
 @IBOutlet var iconImg:UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var titleLbl:UILabel!
@IBOutlet var timeField:UITextField!
@IBOutlet var activeSwtch:UISwitch!
@IBOutlet var durationLbl:UILabel!
@IBOutlet var minsLbl:UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    //Styling
    timeField.layer.borderColor = Colors.REALLIGHTGREY.CGColor
    timeField.layer.borderWidth = Numbers.BORDERREG
    timeField.layer.cornerRadius = Numbers.CORNERRADIUS
    timeField.tintColor = Colors.REDNESS

    activeSwtch.onTintColor = Colors.REDNESS

    self.showsReorderControl = true
}

func getTableView() -> UITableView?{
    var tableView:UITableView? = nil
    var view:UIView = self

    while !view.isKindOfClass(UITableView.self) && view.superview != nil {
        view = view.superview!
    }

    if view.isKindOfClass(UITableView.self) {
        tableView = (view as! UITableView)
    }

    return tableView
}

@IBAction func activeSwtchTouch(){

    if self.activeSwtch.on{
        self.titleLbl.enabled = true
        self.timeField.enabled = true
        self.durationLbl.enabled = true
        self.minsLbl.enabled = true
        self.iconImg.alpha = 1.0
        self.showsReorderControl = true
    }
    else{
        let tableView = self.getTableView()

        if tableView != nil {
            let fromPath = tableView!.indexPathForCell(self)!
            let toPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: tableView!.numberOfRowsInSection(fromPath.section) - 1, inSection: fromPath.section)
            print("FROM: " + String(fromPath.row) + ":" + String(fromPath.section))
            print("TO: " + String(toPath.row) + ":" + String(toPath.section))
            print("SECTIONS: " + String(tableView!.numberOfSections))
            print("ROWS: " + String(tableView!.numberOfRowsInSection(fromPath.section)))
            tableView!.moveRowAtIndexPath(fromPath, toIndexPath: toPath)
            self.titleLbl.enabled = false
            self.timeField.enabled = false
            self.durationLbl.enabled = false
            self.minsLbl.enabled = false
            self.iconImg.alpha = 0.5
            self.showsReorderControl = false
        }
    }
}
```

Of Note: The custom delegate method for moveRowAtIndexPath seems to only be called when drag-to-reorder is used, but not when the UISwitch touch triggers. At the very least, the breakpoints in that method do not get hit when UISwitch touch trigger is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dumb mistake. This line `self.eventTypes.removeObject(sourceIndexPath.row)` should be `self.eventTypes.removeObject(object)`. The object was never being removed, and therefore, when a reload or update finishing was being called, it was not able to determine properly the amount of items, since it was growing with each move.